# How can I create a sh script for running five osmocom scripts?

Tags: linux

How can I create a sh script for starting my osmocom applications with a one code?
For example I created `starter.sh`. It contains these: `osmo-stp` & `osmo-pcu` & `osmo-bsc` & `osmo-msc`.
But İt can only open `osmo-stp` and doesn't open other applications. Like this:

```
root@kali:~# ./starter.sh
Copyright (C) 2015-2017 by Harald Welte <laforge@gnumonks.org>
Contributions by Holger Freyther, Neels Hofmeyr
License GPLv2+: GNU GPL Version 2 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Free Software lives by contribution.  If you use this, please contribute!
```

How can I create a sh script for opening all osmocom applications with one prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Would running them in the background work for you? You can literally use `&` at the end of a command to run it in background. So, your `starter.sh` would look like -

```
osmo-stp &
osmo-pcu &
osmo-bsc &
osmo-msc &
```